# Bootstrap tooltip for form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I am fairly new to bootstrap and cant seem to get this right. I am using tooltip javascript functionality, on form validation, which popsup when there is validation errors in the input field, i want tooltip to appear when ever there is validation check errors in the input field onBlur and disappear on focus

My HTML is:

```
<input class="span2" id="formName" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" type="text"  placeHolder="" onBlur="return validateName();" >
```

my javascript is

```
function validateName()
        {
        var x=document.getElementById("formName").value;
        if (x==null || x==""){
          $('#formName').tooltip({ 'title': 'Name Must Not Be Empty!' });
        } else { $('#formName').tooltip('hide') }   
    }
```

Currently it is following default behaviour of appearing on mouseover, i want to make it appear whenever cursor leaves the input filed

Answer (score 0):

i guess you should go through this http://api.jquery.com/blur/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>temp-stackoverflow</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="field" class="text-field">toggle cursor in and out of text box</input>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.text-field').blur(function() {
      $('body').attr('bgcolor', "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16))
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the event trigger to `onkeyup`:

```
<input class="span2" id="formName" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" type="text"  placeHolder="" onkeyup="return validateName();" >
```

Comment: As i mentioned, the problem at hand is not the tooltip functioning, it is appearing on mouseover[hover] on the input tag, what i want is it should appear onBlur or when cursor leaves the relevant input tag...

Comment: on blur is hard to track. Mention somebody using the tab key to navigate to the form, the mouse would never enter or leave the input field! The onliest action which you can really trigger is when a key is pressed inside the input... (or the content changes due a clipboard pasting via mouse)