# Bootstrap 5 tooltip location not working on form validation with data attribute

Tags: validation, tooltip, custom-data-attribute, bootstrap-5

Reading through the docs with [tooltip form validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/?#tooltips) it appears below the input. When I read the docs regarding customization of [tooltip placement with the data attribute](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#examples) it would appear this should work:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <form class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-select" aria-label="Select Day" required>
          <option selected disabled value="">Please select a day</option>
          <option value="mon">Monday</option>
          <option value="tues">Tuesday</option>
        </select>
        <div class="invalid-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Day tooltip">
          Please select a day
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col">
      <button id="build" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

when adding:

```
data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top"
```

Research:

- [How to put bootstrap tooltip on textbox if validation fails for that textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182235/how-to-put-bootstrap-tooltip-on-textbox-if-validation-fails-for-that-textbox)
- [showing validation error message like tooltip [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23021973/showing-validation-error-message-like-tooltip/23022124)
- [How to put a tooltip on input when its not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784925/how-to-put-a-tooltip-on-input-when-its-not-valid)
- [Javascript validation with bootstrap tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435882/javascript-validation-with-bootstrap-tooltip)
- [Bootstrap tooltip for form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220523/bootstrap-tooltip-for-form-validation)
- [How do I create a tooltip showing a validation error pointing to a field when the submit button is pressed using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172605/how-do-i-create-a-tooltip-showing-a-validation-error-pointing-to-a-field-when-th/51172834)

In Bootstrap 5 how can I modify the location of the validation tooltip with a data attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a complicated question to answer, but I'll try.

The [Tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/?#tooltips) method for form validation described in the docs does not leverage the [ToolTips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/) API ... it just uses it's styling insofar as color and shape.

How it works is with a "~" (immediately preceding) CSS selector and is set at "display: none" initially.  Once a form validates, it triggers the styling with a [CSS :valid selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_valid.asp).  So the "tooltip" must immediately precede the form element *(`input` or any of the others)*.

The "`valid-toolip`"/"`invalid-tooltip`" classes have 3 very important attributes you need to be aware of:

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
```

Also, the form field is contained in a "`position-relative`" class, so the "tooltip" positions itself at the bottom of that `div` *(or rather at 100% from the top)*.

If for example you wanted to position the "tooltip" at the top of the "field container div" you'd need to set "`top: 0`" in some custom CSS class *or* just inline with a style attribute, like so:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 position-relative">
    <label for="validationTooltip02" class="form-label">Last name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip02" value="Otto" required>
    <div class="valid-tooltip" style="top: 0">
      Looks good! (Top)
    </div>
  </div>
```

Have a look at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinorodrigues/qwfcb569/25/) for some examples.

Comment: Hi, Why you use `[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]` at js if you do not have such elements on page?